# Calling Semaphore bounded thread from function results in `NameError: name 'sema' is not defined`

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore

If I want to limit the number of threads to create, I use a Semaphore like in the example below

```
def TestFunction( m, n ):
    sema.acquire()
    print(m+n)
    sema.release()

maxthreads = 2
sema = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)
j=6

for i in range(0, 2*2): #totalNumberOfRows
    thread = threading.Thread(target=TestFunction,args=( i , j ))
    thread.start()
```

However, if I call the threads from a function, I run into a `NameError: name 'sema' is not defined` error.

```
def TestFunction( m, n ):
    sema.acquire()
    print(m+n)
    sema.release()

def CallThreads(k):

    maxthreads = 2
    sema = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)
    j=6

    for i in range(0, k*2): #totalNumberOfRows
        thread = threading.Thread(target=TestFunction,args=( i , j ))
        thread.start()

for mstr in range(0, 10): 
    CallThreads(mstr)
```

In this case, should I define `sema` outside both functions? If so, would the `thread` created in `CallThreads` be able to recognize this `sema` and use it inside `TestFunction` ?

Possible Solution:

```
def TestFunction( m, n ):
    sema.acquire()
    print(m+n)
    sema.release()

def CallThreads(k):

    maxthreads = 2
    j=6

    for i in range(0, k*2): #totalNumberOfRows
        thread = threading.Thread(target=TestFunction,args=( i , j ))
        thread.start()

for mstr in range(0, 10): 
    sema = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)
    CallThreads(mstr)
```

Comment: Variables defined in a function are local to this function so a global variable outside of a function is needed for that.

Comment: By the way: You do not restrict the number of created threads, only the number of running threads while more are waiting (and use system resources while doing so).